# How does minecraft store its music files?

Tags: java, audio, encryption, jar, minecraft

Where does the music files, that is played in Minecraft, get stored in the latest `minecraft.jar`?

Just extracting the jar-file as a zip-file, doesn't reveal any audio files, only `.class`, `.png`, `.txt`, `.lang` and one `.bin` file for the font glyphs.

How does Minecraft encrypt the audio files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The audio files come from [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftResources/), which is just an XML file. They're not encrypted, and the client downloads them as it needs them. Don't do anything naughty, and read through the Minecraft [brand guidelines](http://minecraft.net/brand), which covers third party usage of these resources.